# "n.split is not a function" when trying to setup application insights monitoring for Azure Function App

Tags: azure-functions, azure-monitoring

I am trying to find a way to see log output for a production azure function.  If I click on "setup" for logs/monitoring I get this:

[image]

Hitting configure gives this:

[image]

Comment: Same issue for me.

Comment: In the end, I used a different route to enabling the logs, and its now working. I clicked on the "logs" tab and configured a new logging resource.

Answer (score 1):

This might happen when either "Application Insights" is not configured for this Function App Or the one which was configured was deleted.

To verify it, on Azure Portal go to your "Function App" --> "Application Insights (*under Settings*)" --> check if it says that "Your app is connected to resource: [AppInsights Resource Name]".

If the AppInsights resource is configured for the Function App, check if the logs in AppInsights have entries from recent times (*to ensure that captured telemetry is getting ingested in here*)

In case this does not resolve the issue, I would suggest reaching out to [Microsoft Azure Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/options/) so that it can be investigated from backend.